# Can you force PHP to view a numeric key as an associative array key?

Tags: php, arrays

Having an odd problem with an associative array.  This code:

```
$sql = DB::select('id','process_id')->from('field')->order_by('process_id')->order_by('sort_order');
$query = $sql->execute();

foreach($query->as_array() as $row){
    $results[$row['id']] = $this->get_field($row['id']);
}
```

creates an array with a numeric key.  In my development environment the array is treated as an associative array and is ordered exactly as it's built from the query.  However, in production it's treating the key as a number and sorting according to the ID.  If I force PHP to consider the key associative by:

```
$results["a".$row['id']] = $this->get_field($row['id']);
```

it uses the MySQL sort.  Unfortunately though there's a lot of code in place that depends on the key just being the ID.

Does anyone have any thoughts on why there might be a difference between servers?  Any ideas for a workaround?

Comment: Try $results["".$row['id']].  I'm not sure how PHP will treat that value, it depends where the interpreting happens.

Comment: That is very odd... PHP does not automatically sort keys, it stores it in insertion order. Are you sure the query result is the same both times? There is actually no difference between numerical and associative arrays in PHP. It's the same data structure.

Comment: The problem is somewhere else... not in the posted code.

Comment: The premise of this question (sorting) is false. Voting to close as not a real question.

Comment: I tried $results["".$row['id']] ... it still interprets as numeric.

Comment: @Felix, the resulting order if inserting with `"a".$row['id']` is [a294][a296][a301][a302][a305][a303][a304][a297][a298][a299][a300]  If inserting with just $row['id'] the order is [294][296][297][298][299][300][301][302][303][304][305]

Comment: @minimal: It's hard to tell what's going on with the information you've prodvided. from the code, it should not make a difference. Ensure that you're debugging at the right place. Knowing what changes behavior does not mean knowing where the behavior is actually created. So find the right place where the flaw of your code is. Can't remember a PHP version where that what you describe was the case. Please take care.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe try casting it as a string?

```
$results[(string)$row['id']] = $this->get_field($row['id']);
```

Or if all you care about is order, just put them in as a normal list:

```
$results[] = $this->get_field($row['id']);
```

Comment: that shouldn't change the order

Comment: @Brendan: You can not use (string) numbers as keys, they will always be a number in PHP ;)